# What do the work credits do in Dank Memer? Can you trade them in for gems or coins?

Tags: discord, dank-memer

I recently got the RPG Discord game bot, *Dank Memer*. I've been having fun, doing "work shifts" in the game, and getting work credits. I've been wondering what the work credits do. Can you trade them in for gems, coins, or what? Credits are also known by this symbol: ⏣

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work credits are not specific to work: ⏣ represents the currency as a whole. Claiming dailies and doing other commands such as /search will also give you money. Using the /shop view command, you can buy items from the shop with them.

However, you cannot obtain gems with the currency, you have to pay real money for those.

Comment: The currency cannot be used to buy things; you need use gold coins (real money bought) and gems (real money bought). I'm very confused

Comment: Coins are not real money bought. In this example image, I gain 3,333 ⏣ from a work shift and 50,000 ⏣ from /daily. Both of those add up to 53,333⏣ and translate to coins when I do /shop view.
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/802176475230371864/1152635306370150410/image.png?width=385&height=671